# Mac Excel 2011 VBA UDF not working - SET or FIND command seems to be the issue

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am converting a spreadsheet from Excel 2007 to Mac Excel 2011.  I have tried for hours to solve my problem, without success, so any help would be appreciated!

This UDF finds a string in a range, then returns the value one cell below the found cell.  The SET command returns nothing in the Mac version, but works in Excel 2007.

```
Function FindRng(Fnd As String)
Application.Volatile

Dim Rng As Range
If Fnd = "" Then
    FindRng = 0
    GoTo 109
End If
With Sheets("Matrix").Range("G2:FZ13")
         Set Rng = .Find(What:=Fnd, _
                After:=.Cells(2, 7), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        FindRng = Sheets("Matrix").Cells(Rng.Row + 1, Rng.Column).Value
    Else
        FindRng = 0
    End If
End With

109 End Function
```

Answer (score 6):

Find doesn't work in a UDF called from a cell in 2011 (same problem that existed in PC versions pre-Office XP) so you'll either have to loop and test each cell (Loading the data into an array should be faster than reading cell-by-cell) or process one row at a time using application.match for example.

Comment: + 1 True that!!! Similarly, you cannot use `.FindNext` in Excel UDF in any versions of Excel (not tested in xl2013)

Comment: What a fail on Microsoft's part. Come on!