# Why does my function work on Windows but not on OS X?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

This is my function:

```
Function FindLast(searchTerm As String) As Integer

    Set cell = Worksheets("nameofsheet").Columns("A").Find(what:=searchTerm, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

    If cell Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print ("Text was not found")
        FindLast = 0
    Else
      Debug.Print ("found")
        FindLast = cell.row
    End If

End Function
```

It works just fine on Windows, yet on Mac it does not. I always get `#REF!` error in the cell.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using on each platform?

Comment: @brandonscript excel 2016 on both

Comment: It works for me in Excel 2011. Are you using it as UDF or in a procedure?

Comment: @SiddharthRout im using it as a user defined function in excel

Comment: Place `OnError Resume Next` before the `Set` ............... **un-tested**

Comment: Try `Set cell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(...)`, just to eliminate the possibility that you had another active workbook. It's difficult to imagine another reason for `#REF!` from your code.

Comment: I do not get any errors in Excel 2011. Nor does it find the value if used in an UDF. In a procedure, however it works.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent the error remains the same unfortunately

Comment: @A.S.H that does not work either

Comment: Can you check something for me? Can you use it in a procedure and check if it works?

Comment: @SiddharthRout maybe i'm mistaken and it is a procedure? I'm very new to VBA and Excel.. the formula im using my function in looks like this: 

`=SUM(INDIRECT("'sheetname'!C"&MATCH($C22;'sheetname'!$A:$A;0)&":C"&FindLast($C22)))`

Comment: It is a UDF. Type `=FindLas‌​t($C22)` in a blank excel cell and see if you are still getting the error? I think the error is not because of the code but because of `INDIREKT`

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=indirect+ref+error

Comment: @SiddharthRout im getting 0. Which is not an error but it should be 3

Comment: The error is not because of your code. It is because of `INDIRECT()`

Also if I am not wrong, `.Find` in Excel Mac UDF doesn't work. It will not give you error message. It will give you `0` like I mentioned couple of comments above :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896566/mac-excel-2011-vba-udf-not-working-set-or-find-command-seems-to-be-the-issue

Comment: I'm starting to understand, thanks. Do you have any idea how i could make this work on mac?

Comment: Posted an answer. You may have to refresh the page to see it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the formula im using my function in looks like this: =SUM(INDIRECT("'sheetname'!C"&MATCH($C22;'sheetname'!$A:$A;0‌​)&":C"&FindLast($C22‌​))) – StB 11 mins ago

The error is not because of your code. It is because of `INDIRECT()`

`.Find` in Excel Mac UDF doesn't work. It will not give you error message like I mentioned in one of comments above. It will give you `0`. Here is another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896566/mac-excel-2011-vba-udf-not-working-set-or-find-command-seems-to-be-the-issue) which confirms the same.

To make it work you will have to use a loop as shown below.

```
Function FindLast(searchTerm As String) As Integer
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

    On Error GoTo WHOA

    Set oSht = Sheets("nameofsheet")

    lastRow = oSht.Range("A" & oSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If oSht.Range("A" & i).Value = searchTerm Then
            MsgBox "Value Found in Cell " & oSht.Range("A" & i).Address
            FindLast = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    Exit Function
WHOA:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Function
```